# While loop loops for third time although it's condition in my eyes isn't met and therefore prints a null string

Tags: c++, pointers, struct

I have created a small station line program where the user can make their own list of stations all pointing to each other. I am inexperienced with pointers and structs as you'll clearly see but any assistance would be appreciated.

My code works up to the point of listing the stations now that the first (one after start) has been named. It loops for an additional time and of course cannot print a null string so it comes up with an error. How can I fix this error and how dumb am I?

```
using namespace std;

struct Station
{
    string name;
    Station *next;
};


int main()
{
    string startName = "Start";

    Station *start = new Station;   
    start->name = startName;
    start->next = NULL; 

    Station *pointer = NULL;

    char addkey = 'n';
    char response;
    bool adding = true;

    cout << "Enter 'n' to add a New Station" << endl;
    cin >> response;

    if (response == addkey)
    {
        do
        {
            char addAgain;
            string newName;
            string fromStation;

            Station *beforePointer = pointer;

            cout << "\nEnter New Station Name" << endl;
            cin >> newName;

            pointer = start;

            cout << "\nStation List:" << endl << start->name << endl;   
            do
            {
                beforePointer = pointer;
                cout << beforePointer->name << endl; // Issue running this line the second run of the code, third run of the do-while loop. String at start->next->next->name; a nullptr
                pointer = pointer->next; 
            }
            while (beforePointer->next != nullptr);

            cout << "\nEnter Station it is from (top to bottom)" << endl;
            cin >> fromStation;

            pointer = start->next;

            bool pointed;
            pointed = false;

            if (start->name == fromStation)
            {
                string placeholdString;
                Station *placeholdPointer;

                Station *newStation = new Station;

                if (start->next != NULL) // Hasn't been tested as of yet
                {
                    placeholdString = start->next->name;
                    placeholdPointer = start->next;
                    start->next = newStation;
                    start->next->name = newName;
                    start->next->next = placeholdPointer;
                    start->next->name = placeholdString;
                    pointed = true;
                }
                else
                {
                    start->next = newStation;
                    start->next->name = newName;
                    pointed = true;
                }

            }
            else
            {
                pointer = start->next;

                do
                {
                    if (pointer->name == fromStation)
                    {
                        string placeholdString;
                        Station *placeholdPointer;

                        Station *newStation = new Station;

                        if (pointer->next != NULL) // Hasn't been tested as of yet
                        {
                            placeholdString = pointer->next->name;
                            placeholdPointer = pointer->next;
                            pointer->next = newStation;
                            pointer->next->name = newName;
                            pointer->next->next = placeholdPointer;
                            pointer->next->name = placeholdString;
                            pointed = true;
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            pointer->next = newStation;
                            pointer->next->name = newName;
                            pointed = true;
                        }       
                    }
                    if (pointed == false)
                    {
                        pointer = pointer->next;
                    }
                }
                while (pointer->next != NULL);
            }


            cout << "\nWould you like to add more?" << endl << "Enter 'n' again" << endl;
            cin >> addAgain;

            if (addAgain != addkey)
            {
                adding = false;
            }
            else if (addAgain == addkey)
            {
                adding = true;
            }
        } 
        while (adding == true);
    }

    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I note your loop has: `while (adding = true)`. That should surely be `while( adding == true )` (double equals) or better `while( adding )`.

Comment: Omg I'm so bad, I'll update it and check back in

Comment: Ok fixed that part. Issue still remains the same, though that was expected. Thanks though!

Comment: Have you stopped through it in a debugger to see what's happening?

Answer (score 0):

From your code (the do-while loop):

```
    /* Add #include <assert.h> at top of file */

    // Run #1
    assert( pointer != NULL ) ;
    beforepointer  = pointer ; // beforepointer == pointer == start

    assert( beforepointer != NULL ) ;
    assert( beforepointer->name != NULL ) ;

    cout << beforepointer->name << endl ; // Will print 'Start'
    pointer = pointer->next ; // pointer->next == start->next == NULL
    assert( pointer != NULL ) ; // SHOULD FAIL HERE (will abort)

    // (pointer is now NULL)

    // Run #2
    beforepointer = pointer ; // beforepointer == pointer == NULL
    assert( beforepointer != NULL ) ; // This would fail too
    cout << beforepointer(== NULL)->name << endl ; // *** Segmentation violation!
    ...
```

You are no longer pointing to anything valid on the 2nd run, beforepointer is NULL.

A better way to print out the list would be:

```
beforepointer = pointer ;
assert( beforepointer != NULL ) ;

while ( beforepointer != NULL ) {
    assert( beforepointer->name != NULL ) ;

    cout << beforepointer->name << endl ;
    beforepointer = beforepointer->next;
}
```

EDIT: 
Paraphrasing your code sample, and using the standard c++ library, you could simplify it all as follows (using vectors):

```
/**
 * Wrapper function to prompt user for input
 */
istream & queryUser( const string & prompt, string & answer ) {
  cout << prompt << ' ' << flush ;
  getline( cin, answer ) ;
  return cin;
}

/** Always useful emptiness test function */
bool isBlankOrEmpty( const string & s ) {
    return s.empty() || s.find_first_not_of( " \t") == string::npos ;
}
/**
 * The big main
 */
int main() {
  vector<string> stations ; // list of station names

  // ... Accept user input as long as input is entered
  string newStationName ;
  while( queryUser( "Enter new station name (or hit ENTER to exit)", newStationName ) ) {

    // ... Quit if the line is empty
    if ( isBlankOrEmpty( newStationName ) ) {
        break ;
    }

    // ... Locate insertion point
    vector<string>::iterator insertionPoint = stations.end() ; // append by default

    // ... Have user specify where to insert the new station (if there is such an option)
    if ( stations.size() > 1 ) {

        // ... Where to insert?
        string fromStation ;
        if ( queryUser("Enter station it is from (top to bottom)", fromStation) && ! isBlankOrEmpty( fromStation ) ) {
            vector<string>::iterator it = std::find( stations.begin(), stations.end(), fromStation ) ;
            if ( it != stations.end() ) {
                insertionPoint = ++it ; // move to position after the fromStation
            }
        }
    }

    // ... Insert the new station name
    stations.insert( insertionPoint, newStationName ) ;

    cout << "Your station list:" << endl ;
    for ( auto & stationName : stations ) {
        cout << stationName << endl ;
    }
  }

  return 0 ;
}
```

Comment: I like the look of that loop better yeah. Though the same error comes up. Is this still the null pointer attempting to point to a string? I'm actually a bit lost as to the error now. There isn't a string for it to point at either so possibly that.
Exception thrown: read access violation.
std::_String_alloc<std::_String_base_types<char,std::allocator<char> > >::_Get_data(...) returned 0xCDCDCDCD.

Comment: One thing you could do it add a bunch of asserts (see edited answer).  That way you'll catch any violation of your basic assumptions.

Comment: I wish I could assert whether a string is or isn't NULL. Would make this so much easier haha. Thanks for telling me about asserts, hadn't heard about them before.

Comment: Is there any reason you have to use pointers?  The standard C++ library has all sorts of containers that take care of this sort of thing.  For example, depending on your specific use case, you can use std::vector, std::queue, std::deque, all well documented at http://www.cplusplus.com/reference

Comment: Thanks for this, really. Would I still be using pointers in that case or would vectors alone work. This is part of a programming assignment and I've been asked to implement pointers.

Comment: No need to use pointers when using standard containers.  I've added an example to my original answer.  It uses vectors, but you might want to use one of the other containers as well.  If this works for you, don't forget to upvote my answer (thanks!)

Comment: Your code works amazingly thank you! Though I do still need to figure out how to do this simple thing using pointers, definitely upvoting!

Comment: If you look at the interface methods for any standard container, it gives you a glimpse into how best to wrap the details of list manipulation into a class.  For example, if you wanted to write your own list class, you could define your own insert() and remove() methods that hide all the ugly pointer details.  It then makes code much clearer ...

Answer (score 0):

```
                        Station *newStation = new Station;
```

The problem is you aren't initializing your new struct object.  `new` doesn't not make any guarantee about the state of the memory it returns.  So your newStation->next could have any value in it causing it to potentially fail the nullptr/NULL checks.